# Handling JSP Compilation Errors

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I want to handle Compilation error for a particular JSP.
Here is the scenario:

User deploys an ear into IBM Websphere and then manually sets the classpath for some third-party JARs. The application works fine. If the user forgets to add the classpath to the ear, he gets compilation errors while trying to access the JSP page.

We need to handle the compilation error for this particular JSP page and show a custom error page with a user-friendly message like: "Please add the JARs to classpath"

Answer (score 0):

for tomcat that uses servlet 3.0, use error pages inside web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>your compilatione exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage</location>
</error-page>
```

nce Servlet 3.0 those elements are namely optional.

for earlier versions, you'd have to configure it at the container level, and create a custom error report valve class. You can then specify it as errorReportValveClass attribute of the  [element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html) in /conf/server.xml file.

For other containers, read their documentation